# Merging two .csv tables one with header other - not

Tags: linux, csv, columns, bioinformatics, table

I need to merge two .csv tables,

one that contains the following info with NO HEADER:

```
gene0   ABCD
gene1   xyz
gene2   1234
```

..etc

Another table has a header and information like that:

```
gene_id sample1
gene0   135
gene1   5468
gene2   65
```

... etc

What I would like to have is

```
gene_id sample1
ABCD    135
xyz     5468
1234    65
```

Is it even possible to merge these two and, if yes, what is the best way to do it?

Comment: Are those "genes" always come in consecutive order?

Answer (score 0):

For the case when all *"genes"* come in consecutive order:
 *one-line* combination of **`head`** + **`tail`** + **`join`** commands:

```
head -1 file2.csv ; join --header -j1 -o1.2,2.2 file1.csv <(tail +2 file2.csv)
```

Sample output:

```
gene_id sample1
ABCD 135
xyz 5468
1234 65
```